# Megnto 2 - table 'magento.store_website' doesn't exist

Tags: database, magento2.3.2, table

I am a newbie to Magento. My friend requested me to make some changes to his existing Magento 2 website and gave a Full CPanel backup. When I executed the Database dump, I noticed that only a few tables were present. Anyway, when I tried accessing the website from my local, I am getting this error

> **table 'magento.store_website' doesn't exist**.

I am not sure whether this is a difference between Production and Developer mode or is it the backup doesn't contain the actual database dump. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have production database backup safe before doing anything.

First check your local magento installation is working properly if not you need to re-install.

If you are trying to install it over the same installation, try to uninstall eexisting setup first

> /magento_root/bin/magento setup:uninstall

[Official Doc here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall.html)

Once your local setup is working fine import production database to your local and test.